# show image from two different tables using one query and one php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two select statement in one query in loadimage.php fle and display it in two different procees, one image for the event and one image for news.
my code goes like this

loadimage.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("pcnl");
$q="select * from tbl_event where event_ID = ".$_GET['id'];
$rec=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($q));
$image=$rec['event_img'];
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($image));
header("Content-type: image/".$rec['event_imgExt']);
echo $image;

$sqlmain="select * from tbl_news where news_ID = ".$_GET['mainid'];
$mainimg=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sqlmain));
$mainimage=$mainimg['news_img'];
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($mainimage));
header("Content-type: image/".$mainimg['news_ext']);
echo $mainimage;
?>
```

event.php

```
<img src="loadimage.php?id=<?php echo $events[id];?>" width="700px" height="350px">
```

news.php

```
<img src="loadimage.php?mainid=<?php echo $main['news_ID'];?>" width="300px" height="350px">
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't asked any question, said what you expect to happen, said what did happen, told us about the errors which should have been logged when you ran this.

You can't return multiple resources in response to a single HTTP request. (this is not strictly true, but that's like talking about string theory when you're still getting the basics of arithmetic).

BTW your current script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Try this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("pcnl");
$t='event'==$_GET['itype'] ? 'tbl_event' : 'tbl_news';

$q="select * from $t where event_ID = ".(integer)$_GET['id'];
if ($rec=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($q))) {
   $image=$rec['event_img'];
   header('Content-Length: '.strlen($image));
   header("Content-type: image/".$rec['event_imgExt']);
   echo $image;
} else {
   header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', 404);
}
```

and...

```
<img src="loadimage.php?itype=event&id=<?php echo $events['id'];?>"...

<img src="loadimage.php?itype=main&id=<?php echo $main['news_ID'];?>"...
```

Or better yet just have a single table holding the data.

Comment: i want to display an image using that loadimage.php file with two queries in it and has a different purpose. thanks for your suggestion i will try your code :)